# Customizing onClickItem listner - ListActivity

Tags: android

I am creating a contact list view, diplaying user name,user email and user id. Now while clicking on particular item i want to post some event to server based on the user id. How to get the user id inside the onClickItem listener, as user id is long value. i am able to get the user name that means the text but not the user id.

Comment: can you put your ArrayAdapter creation related code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listView has onCLicklistener that has parameter position.If you are using arrayList to inflate ListView then you can use this positon to get corresponding object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the user id to tag using `View.setTag` and `View.getTag`. There are two version available choose the one you need. This way you can attach the user id as tag and then get it back.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int, java.lang.Object)

You code should look like:

```
view.setTag(Long.valueOf(id));


.....
onClickListener(..) {
  Long id = (Long)view.getTag();
}
```

Comment: can we use setTag multiple times in getView() ?? while scrolling it is getting crashed. What to do then ??

Comment: Are you using some Adapter? If not then you can look at the other version of setTag which is key/value pair.

Comment: yea i am using ArrayAdapter inside i am overidding getView(). can you please look it for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should make your own bean class which contains your userid and put it in List (or ArrayList)

then create an adapter by creating a class extending ArrayAdapter (for instance) to bind your list of this bean class

register a listener either using onItemClickListener or View listener in your row if you inflate your custom layout.

get the position and use it to retrieve your userid on your bean list.

Here's my snippet

```
public class ListActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
private Context context;
private RowAdapter adapter;
private ArrayList<Row> rowList = new ArrayList<Row>();

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    context = ListActivity.this;

    initRows();

    adapter = new RowAdapter(context, rowList);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

private void initRows() {
    Row row = new Row(1);
    rowList.add(row);

    row = new Row(2);
    rowList.add(row);
}

public class Row {
    long userid = 0;

    public Row(long userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public long getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(long userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
}

public class RowAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Row> {

    private Context context;

    public RowAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Row> bindList) {
        super(context, R.layout.row_layout, bindList);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;

        if(view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout, null);
        }

        //if you use some additional View you can retrieve your position using this
        Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {                
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateSelected(position);
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

}

//or if you rather just listen on row click then you can retrieve your position using this
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {
    updateSelected(position);
}

private void updateSelected(int position) {
    rowList.get(position).getUserid();
    //have it your way
}
```

}